# AttributeError:'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeCo' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'

Tags: python, json, protocol-buffers, proto

```
def get_ad_full_details(ad_json, current_topics, ad_group_ad, ad):
        mandatory_data = {
            "ad_group_ad.ad.responsive_search_ad.headlines": ad_group_ad.ad.responsive_search_ad.headlines,
            "ad_group_ad.ad.responsive_search_ad.descriptions": ad_group_ad.ad.responsive_search_ad.descriptions}
    ad_json["mandatory_data"] = mandatory_data
```

when I run `json.dumps(ad_json)` I get `AttributeError:'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeCo' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'`. I've tried to follow this [post](https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision/issues/70#issuecomment-406194079) but it still gives the same error.

I've tried to iterate and map the `ad_group_ad.ad.responsive_search_ad.headlines` repeated protof field to its "[text]" values, but the code fails.

Any idea, how I can fetch the "text" member of this repeated proto field?

I can use regex, but thought their might be an easier way